# How to reformat the contents of a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

move_lines.sh originally looked like this:

```
mv /home/user/filename.txt /home/user/filename.txt.old
mv /home/user/filename1.txt /home/user/filename1.txt.old
```

Code used so far:

```
awk '{print $1,$3}' move_lines.sh >> move_lines.sh
cd /home/user/oldfiles 
currentdir=$(pwd)
echo "$currentdir" >> move_lines.sh
echo "$currentdir" >> move_lines.sh
unset $currentdir
```

Current output:

```
mv /home/user/filename.txt /home/user/filename.txt.old
mv /home/user/filename1.txt /home/user/filename1.txt.old
mv /home/user/filename1.txt.old 
mv /home/user/filename1.txt.old
/home/user/oldfiles/
/home/user/oldfiles/
```

The goal is to make it look like this:

```
mv /home/user/filename.txt /home/user/filename.txt.old
mv /home/user/filename1.txt /home/user/filename1.txt.old
mv /home/user/filename1.txt.old /home/user/oldfiles/
mv /home/user/filename1.txt.old /home/user/oldfiles/
```

Unsure how to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have to do this for a lot of files? Seems like it would be easier to just do by hand in a text editor than try to identify the exact rule used to move later lines onto earlier lines.

Comment: how do you detemrine (programmatically) which lines should be merged? sure, with the small sample given it's easy to see the duplicate target directories but what if there are differently named target directories? are 'broken' lines limited to just those entries with a target *directory*, or could the target be a *file*?

Comment: Hi chepner & markp-fuso. Yes, I would like this done for many files. What I posted is not a small sample of the file, but the entire file. All 6 lines make up the entire file. The target directory '/oldfiles/' would always be the same and never change across all files. Please let me know if I minunderstood your concerns. Hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Hi Cyrus, my apologies. I have edited my post and included my own code.

Comment: Why are you renaming and moving it to a second directory in two steps? `mv /home/user/filename.txt /home/user/oldfiles/filename.txt.old`?

Comment: @Cyrus I did get a chance to review your answer as well and I appreciate your time. Thanks for the information and your patience. Still learning the ropes and am eager to continue doing so.

Comment: @chepner I am renaming the file to help me distinguish between the old and newer versions of the same file, then moving it to a backup directory. Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all clarification, requested information or background information there instead of using comments for this purpose. The script marked as your goal will **first** move `/home/user/filename1.txt` to `/home/user/filename1.txt.old`, **then** move `/home/user/filename1.txt.old` to `/home/user/oldfiles/` twice. The second attempt will fail. So the result will be the same as with `mv /home/user/filename1.txt /home/user/oldfiles/`. There are probably errors in your code examples. Please make sure to **copy&paste** the code you have run yourself, don't retype it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can correct this using Python like this:

Let's say your input file is like this

[image: Input file]

Assuming that:

- Line 5 should go behind line 3
- Line 6 should go behind line 4,

here's the code you can write

```
import os

input_file = 'input.txt'
output_file = 'output.txt'
default_path = '/home/user/oldfiles/'

# remove the output file
if os.path.exists(output_file):
    os.remove(output_file)

# read all lines from input file
with open(input_file, 'r') as infile:
    input_lines = infile.readlines() 

# let's store good lines in output_lines and 
# lines with missing last argument in orphaned_files
output_lines = []
orphaned_lines = []

# loop through all the read lines
for line in input_lines:
    
    # remove empty spaces and new line characters at the end of the line
    line = line.strip()
    print('Reading line ', line)

    # split by space and count # of arguments
    arguments = line.split(' ')
    print('Arguments count is ', len(arguments))

    # this is the ideal line. Copy it to output_lines
    if len(arguments) > 2:
        print('Adding it to output_lines')
        output_lines.append(line)

    # this line is missing the last argument. Hold it in orphaned_lines
    if len(arguments) == 2:
        print('Found orphaned')
        orphaned_lines.append(line)

    # we found just the path. Add that to the first orphaned_line
    # then, take that new line and put it in output_lines
    if len(arguments) == 1:

        # if there are any orphaned lines left, add this path
        # to the first orphaned line
        if len(orphaned_lines) > 0:
            print('Adding it to the first orphaned')
            orphaned_line = orphaned_lines.pop(0)
            new_line = orphaned_line + ' ' + line
            output_lines.append(new_line)

# if there are any orphaned lines still left, let's give them
# the default path
for line in orphaned_lines:
    new_line = line + ' ' + default_path
    output_lines.append(new_line)

# write to an output file
with open(output_file, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in output_lines:
        outfile.write(line + '\n')

print('Done')
```

How do you run this file?

- Save the code in a file called test.py
- Assuming your input file that contains imperfect lines is called input.txt
- From command line, type `python3 test.py`
- You will get a file called output.txt that will look like this:

[image: Output file]

## Easier option with AWK

On command line, type:

```
awk '{n=split($0,a); if(n==3) print $0; else if (n==2) print $0" /home/user/oldfiles/" }' input.txt > output.txt
```

In this one-liner, we ask `awk` to:

- split the line (represented by $0). When we split the line, the number of items are returned to a variable called `n`
- If awk finds 3 items, we print the line
- If awk finds 2 items, we print the line followed by a space and the default path you desire
- Otherwise, don't print anything.

The output will go into output.txt and will look the same as the 2nd screenshot above.

## Update

Based on your code, you could just do this on your bash prompt.

```
awk '{n=split($0,a); if(n==3) print $0; else if (n==2) print $0" /home/user/oldfiles/" }' move_lines.sh > new_move_lines.sh
```

Comment: It is useful to wait with an answer until the questioner has shown what he/she has done to answer the question himself.

Comment: @Cyrus yes, I do agree. I make exceptions every now and then for newcomers. They may not have tried anything or may be paralyzed. I used to be like that when I started programming first. So, I empathize with newcomers and share details of what I know. I understand that goes against the norm on SO.

Comment: @zedfoxus Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, it is truly appreciated! However, I am using bash shell instead of python. Thanks again kind sir!

Comment: @Gnash on bash, you should be able to use the `awk` one-liner I have at the end of the answer to get what you want. Give it a shot.

Comment: @Gnash check the last code under my `Update` section of the answer at the bottom. You can run that and that should help you out.

Comment: @zedfoxus I ran your code in the terminal and it looks like it did exactly what I was looking for. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: @Gnash absolutely! I am happy that the code worked for you. Thank you for providing relevant details.